# Using SmtpAppender to only send emails when logging an error or fatal

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging, log4net

I'm using log4net to log different types of messages.
I have added the SmtpAppender to email specific user when logging messages.
However, what I would like to achieve is to be able to only send emails if an error or fatal is logged.
Accroding to my current configuration in the web.config file, I get two emails, one for the error and another one for the rest of the logs.
Global.asax.cs:

```
logger.Info("Info");
logger.Warn("Warning");
logger.Fatal("Fatal");
logger.Error("exception");
```

web.config:

```
<appender name="SmtpAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SmtpAppender">
    <to value="bla@bla.com" />
    <from value="bla@bla.com" />
    <subject value="test logging message" />
    <smtpHost value="*******" />
    <bufferSize value="512" />
    <lossy value="true" />
    <evaluator type="log4net.Core.LevelEvaluator">
        <threshold value="WARN"/>
    </evaluator>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%newline%date [%thread] %-5level %logger- %message%newline%newline%newline" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution, I should just add this tag to the SmtpAppender:

```
<filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
    <levelMin value="ERROR" />
    <levelMax value="FATAL" />
</filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
<appender name="SmtpAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SmtpAppender">
    ...
    <threshold value="WARN"/>
    ...
</appender>
```

(or `threshold value="ERROR"` since you say you want to limit to Error and Fatallevels) rather than:

```
<appender name="SmtpAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SmtpAppender">
    ...
    <evaluator type="log4net.Core.LevelEvaluator">
        <threshold value="WARN"/>
    </evaluator>
    ...
</appender>
```

The log4net documentation or [this message in the log4net user mailing list](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/logging-log4net-user/200509.mbox/%3CDDEB64C8619AC64DBC074208B046611C7694A9@kronos.neoworks.co.uk%3E) explains the difference.

Comment: that resulted in having no email sent at all

Comment: @clarittasafa - you're right; it's because your appender is configured to be lossy, and therefore requires an evaluator.  You could either configure lossy=false, or add an evaluator, depending on your requirements.